# Java: (Micro) benchmark library imports using JMH?

Tags: java, benchmarking, jmh

I have the following code that I am benchmarking using JMH

```java
package org.example;

import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Benchmark;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.BenchmarkMode;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Mode;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class BenchmarkRunner {
    @Benchmark
    @BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
    public void bench_Rand() {
        List<Integer> pages = IntStream.range(0, 256).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
        Collections.shuffle(pages);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        org.openjdk.jmh.Main.main(args);
    }
}
```

While the benchmark works, I am wondering about the latency values incurred for **importing** the libraries in the benchmark code. Is there a way to benchmark the library import together with the code?

Comment: Imports are a compile-time construct. They don't involve any runtime overhead other than the usual classloading.

Comment: What library are you expecting to measure the overhead of importing?  JMH?  IntStream?  In any event, any sane benchmark measures only after everything is fully loaded in, since _all_ JVM code runs slowly as it starts up even after it's initially loaded.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Yes, I wish to know the overhead for the java.util libraries like IntStream and Collectors (if any).

Comment: What kind of overhead are you talking about? Imports are, as previously stated, a compile-time construct. Loading a class takes time but will only incur a cost the first time the class is used. Using an `IntStream` to iterate a range of numbers will likely have more overhead than a traditional for loop. So, the question becomes, what are you trying to benchmark? If it's the call to `shuffle` and you don't want the generation of the list to be counted in the average time, then don't generate the list in the benchmark method. Pass the list in as state.

Comment: Also, make sure to return the shuffled list from the benchmark method or pass it to a `Blackhole` to avoid JIT possibly optimizing away "dead" code.

Comment: @Slaw I just would like to benchmark exactly what is shown in the sample; it's okay for both the list generation and intstream to be together.

Comment: Then your benchmark method seems fine, other than the potential issue described in my second comment. You don't have to worry about "importing" the classes, since `import` statements only have meaning at compile-time. And you don't have to worry about the overhead of class loading, as loading the class will only happen once (and will happen before measurements are taken anyway--during the warmup phase at the latest).

Comment: In retrospect, it feels like what you might be missing is that you need to specify the overhead relative to _what_ -- in short, you need to write a version of the code without the library, and run benchmarks on both, and consider the difference.  Importing is cost-free, yes.  Using the Stream API isn't, and maybe that's what you're interested in.